# How to read Wolfram CDF file in CDF player?

Tags: ubuntu, mathematica

I would like see the source code how the project [The Causal Interpretation of Exciting an Atom by Absorption of Intense Light](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheCausalInterpretationOfExcitingAnAtomByAbsorptionOfIntense/) has been done. 
I have CDF player in my system but I cannot play directly in the browser. 
I do not find the player neither in commandline path by doing `cdf[tab]`.
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

In Mathematica, I see all visualizations correctly with good source codes after doing *Update Thumbnail and snapshots*.

How can use the CDF project file in CDF player?